# Как создать перменную в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Как в JS с помощью "if" создавать переменные?
Мне нужно, чтобы при соблюдении определеной условии создавалась перемнная.

```
let i = prompt('У вас есть ноги?'); if(i=='да'){let q=1;} else if(i=='нет'){let w=2;} alert(q||w);
```

Если точнее проблема в том, что перменная доступна только внутри блока "if".
Как сделать так, чтоюы можно было обращаться к ней в будущем?

Comment: `...; if(i=='да'){var q=1;} ...`

Answer (score 0):

Объявляете переменную => обрабатываете условия => записываете в переменную => обрабатываете переменную.

```js
let i = prompt('У вас есть ноги?'); 
let answer = (i=='да') ? 'у вас ноги есть' : 'камень я не дам';
alert(answer);
```

Если нужны операции посложней, то делается это так

```js
let i = prompt('У вас есть ноги?');

let answer = function(str) {
    if(str === "да")
        return "У вас есть ноги";
    else if (str === "нет")
        return "У вас нет ног?!";
    else
        return "Камень я не дам";
}


console.log(answer(i));
```